# Google Update 20th Nov 2016 - Suddenly increasing index stats

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-search-console, google-search, googlebot

My site is suddenly having a lot more pages indexed. We don't actually have that much content, unless Google is suddenly pulling Analytics URLs from the back office.

Has anyone got an explanation for this? Is it update related? Anyone had similar issues?

[image: Sudden increase in index]

Comment: If you didn't have 38000+ pages, may be your site has been hacked? Check what pages are indexed with site:your site.com

Comment: Nope, but checking the links with no filters on there appear to be a lot of ones blocked explicitly in the robots.txt that aren't being filtered out! Looks like Google has a bug.

Comment: if other allowed pages points to the blocked ones by robots.txt they will be indexed indeed.